# db2 for i : passing a varchar containing comma separated string in an sql procedure in in clause

Tags: sql, db2, procedure, db2-400

i have a string containing comma separated strings in java.. which i m passing to a sql procedure being called in java ...
**here is example of java string:**

```
    String codeString = "'232/232','34fd/34//'";
```

**code in sql db2 for i:**

```
    create procedure history (in id varchar (3), in code varchar (2000))
   ......
   ......
   begin
   insert into table1
   select date_from, date_to, code
   from table2 
   where table2.serial= id
   and table2.status not in (code); 
   end
```

this sql procedure is inserting same string in table1.code but it is not excluding table2.status in in clause..

value being inserted in table1.code is '232/232','34fd/34//' (including all single quotes and commas)

Comment: You need to show us the code of the java call to the stored procedure, I think.

Comment: Procedure call in java is working fine... just problem is with in clause

Comment: OK .... I am unconvinced you can pass a string into the in clause like that. Could you not use " code not like concat('%''',status,'''%') " or something along those lines?

Comment: Then how can i pass string in in clause... what are the possible ways

Comment: I just wonder that when i insert code value in table1..it works fine even no issue with any single quote,comma.. but when i pas it to not in clause its creating problem

Comment: Have you tried the workaround I suggested?

Answer (score 3):

What you are saying here:

```
and table2.status not in (code);
```

is the same as saying:

```
and table2.status <> code;
```

You are **not** saying:

```
and table2.status not in ('232/232','34fd/34//');
```

The reason is that it is checking `status` against the whole of `code`, not some part of `code`. The comma separated list in `code` is not parsed. In fact no variables are parsed. They are taken whole. If you want multiple values in the `in` predicate, you need either multiple literal values, multiple variables, or some combination of that.

It works for the insert because it is just inserting the whole value of `code` into the column of `table1`. No parsing required.

The other option, since you are in a procedure is to parse the comma separated list yourself into an array of strings (not going to show you that here), then use a collection derived table to convert the array to a table that you can use in the `in` predicate like this:

```
status not in (select s.string from UNNEST(stringArray) as s(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
create procedure history (in id varchar (3), in code varchar (2000))

begin
DECLARE stmttxt varchar(2000);
SET stmttxt = 'insert into table1 select date_from, date_to, cast(''' concat replace(code, '''', '''''') concat ''' as varchar(2000)) from table2 where table2.serial= ' concat id concat ' and table2.status not in (' concat code concat ')'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmttxt;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

DB2 for i V7.4

**For SQL:**

```
DECLARE @myVariable varchar(200);
SET @myVariable myVariable = '1,2,3';


IN (SELECT element
          FROM TABLE (
              SYSTOOLS.SPLIT(@myVariable , ',')
            ))
```

**For RPG:**

```
dcl-s myVariable varchar(200);
myVariable = '1,2,3';

IN (SELECT element
          FROM TABLE (
              SYSTOOLS.SPLIT(:myVariable, ',')
            ))
```